# What characterizes the set of matrices that admit non-negative eigenvectors (w. positive eigenvalue)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonnegative-matrices

Let us define the sets

$$S = \{ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} | \exists \lambda, v \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n : Mv = \lambda v\}$$
$$P = \{ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} | \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, v \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n : Mv = \lambda v\}.$$

Obviously, $S \subset P$. By the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) we know that any matrix $M$ such that $M_{ij}>0$ is in $P$.

But this is of course not the only matrices that are in there: For example, consider
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\  -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Is there anything in particular we can tell about $P$? Are there necessary/sufficient conditions, or even some way of telling if a given matrix $M$ should be in $P$?

**Edit**:

Taking into account the comments made by @Ben Grossman and @Ruy below, we have the following observations:

- $P$ is very large. Any matrix which has a column with exactly one nonzero,positive entry lies in this set.
- We could exclude these by only admitting eigenvectors with positive entries:

$$P^+:=\{ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} | \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, v \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}^n : Mv = \lambda v\}$$

- $P^+$ can alternatively described by the following: $$M \in P^+ \iff \exists \ D \ \text{diagonal}, \ D_{ii>0} \ \forall i, \exists c>0, \ \text{s.t.} \
  D^{-1}MD\textbf{1} = c \textbf{1} $$

This is because if $M$ has a fully positive eigenvector $v$ with positive eigenvalue, then we can take $D = \operatorname{diag}(v).$
On the other hand we can take $D\textbf{1}$ as a positive eigenvector.

Comment: A potentially interesting observation: if $v$ has positive entries, then there is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D^{-1}MD$ has a constant row sum

Comment: @BenGrossmann That is true, but that would also hold for $v$ with non-zero entries with different signs, right?

Comment: I don’t see what you mean

Comment: Sorry, I meant a diagonal matrix $D$ *with positive diagonal entries*.

Comment: Any matrix with the same first column as the identity matrix lies in $P$, so this is a really big set!

Comment: @Ruy: That is true, so maybe it is more interesting to only consider completely positive eigenvectors ( see the edit above)

Comment: For instance, every *eventually positive* matrix is in $P^+$, and every *eventually non-negative* matrix is in $P$. There's quite a lot of literature on them.