# When does a symmetric matrix admit a positive eigenvector (i.e. $v_i >0 \forall i$) for a positive eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix.

I am trying to understand when such a matrix possesses a positive eigenvector for a positive eigenvalue, that is a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n, v_i >0 \forall i$, $\lambda>0$, such that

$$Sv = \lambda v.$$

So, basically I am looking for a more general answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184979/when-does-a-matrix-have-a-positive-eigenvector).

It is obvious that if we have one such eigenvector then by orthogonality the other eigenvectors have to have alternating signs.

Also, one can see that in general $S$ should be similar to a matrix with constant row sum (see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448236/what-characterizes-the-set-of-matrices-that-admit-non-negative-eigenvectors-w)).

But this holds in the general case and does not yet use anything about the symmetry of the matrix.

Can we somehow make use of this special structure to find another necessary condition on $S$, or can we maybe get some bounds on $\lambda$?

**Edit**

Of course one can get a very crude bound on the eigenvalues by the row sum of absolute values: Let $v$ be a positive eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$, $||v|| =1$.

Then $$\lambda v_i = \sum_j S_{ij} v_j \leq \sum_j |S_{ij}| v_j \leq \max_k v_k \sum_j |S_{ij}|$$

so
$$ \lambda \leq \max_i \sum_j |S_{ij}|.$$

But this bound is rather useless, since for example
$$S = \begin{pmatrix} n & -n+\epsilon \\ -n+\epsilon & n \end{pmatrix}$$
has eigenpair $\left( (1,1), \epsilon\right)$, while the bound is $2n + \epsilon$.

**Edit2**:

After some more thought one can obtain a bound by the (signed) rowsums, which is better than the above:
Let $v$ be positive eigenvector for $\lambda$ such that $||v||_1 = \sum_i v_i = 1$.
Then by summing up the equation above we get

$$ \lambda \sum_i v_i = \sum_i (\sum_j S_{ij} v_j)  = \sum_i v_i (\sum_j S_{ij})$$

Now for a positive, unit $l_1$-norm vector $v$ and another vector $w$ we have $\min_i w_i \leq v^Tw \leq \max_i w_i$. Thus, with $w_i = (\sum_j S_{ij})$ we obtain
$$ \min_i (\sum_j S_{ij}) \leq \lambda \leq \max_i (\sum_j S_{ij}),$$

which in our above example already determines $\epsilon$.
(In general this shows that for constant row sum $c$ this is the only possible eigenvalue with a positive eigenvector. In fact, one can also say that in the other direction, there only is a positive  eigenvector  corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda =  \max_i (\sum_j S_{ij})$ if the row-sum is constant: Since we required $v_i>0$, the greater/lesser equal above only allows for equality when the row sum is the same for all $i$)

Another (obvious) condition that $S$ has to fulfill, which does not seem to follow from the above, is that in every row, there has to be at least one positive entry (else for that row $\sum_j S_{ij} v_j \leq 0$.)

Comment: Is there any restriction on the degeneracy of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Hsyn what do you have in mind?